# Send email in FusionAuth with STARTTLS

Tags: email, single-sign-on, fusionauth

I am setting email configuration in FusionAuth but is not working and I receive a reject in relay. I found the problem is the email server we are using, need to set the properties `starttls` to `true`.

```
properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
```

But I can not see how to set up this properties in fusionauth

I tried in additional properties of email in `setting/advanced/SMTP` settings to set up some options but there is not documentation of how to do it.

I am receiving this error inside fusionAuth audit log

> Invalid Addresses Cause: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException Message: 454 4.7.1 : Relay access denied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix it, setting some properties in Settings/Settings/Advanced/SMTP Settings

```
  mail.smtp.ssl.trust=*
  mail.smtp.starttls.required=true
  mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
  mail.smtp.starttls.checkserveridentity=false
```

Comment: If you select `TLS` in FusionAuth for SMTP security we will set `mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true`.  I don't know if `mail.smtp.starttls.checkserveridentity=false` is a valid property, I think it is `mail.smtp.ssl.checkserveridentity=false`, which is also the default, so likely not needed. Setting `mail.smtp.ssl.trust=*` is a bit risky, if you know the exact host you want to trust that would be better, this is generally not needed at all if the certificate the SMTP server host provides is trusted. Are you using a third party SMTP service or a private service?